# How to compare array elements according to their content?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

In biology there are aminoacids what have names and so-called codon names. I have a dictionary with them. If i select two or more aminoacids like: Phe, Leu, Ser - I got a 2D array like: [["CTA", "CTC", "CTG", "CTT", "TTA", "TTG"], ["AGC", "AGT", "TCA", "TCC", "TCG", "TCT"], ["TTC", "TTT"]] what includes their codons.

Every codon has 3 position (for example: CTA  - 1st. pos: C, 2nd. pos: T, 3rd pos: A). I want to compare the aminoacids with eachoter and get a code, what shows a universal usability.

With that 3 aminoacids at the and I want a code "T", "CT", "GT or AT or AC".

So first position if C not match in the other arrays, go to the next letter -> T. Examine that 2nd array includes T, if yes go to the 3rd array. If includes save T. Second position. Only examine that codes what starts with T [TTA, TTG][TCA, TCC,TCG,TCT][TTC,TTT]. Second array includes T (second position from TTA), if not add it. Third array includes T or C, if yes save TC. Third position. Examine only what starts wit TT or TC. Examine A and C in seconds array. If includes search in third. If not add the letter.

(Of course if there are no matches in the 3 aminoacids codon like in Ile, Val, Pro - ["ATT","ATC","ATA"], ["GTT","GTC","GTA","GTG"], ["CCT","CCC","CCA","CCG"]. It should examine that 3 letters, and at the end want a code like "AGC", "TC", "T or C or A")

At the and I want a universal code like: TYW  where Y means CT and W means AT

I tried a lot of method, but there are didn't work. I have no idea how to start it.

```
//aminoacid dictionary - name and codons
var aminoacids = {
    "Phe" : ["TTT","TTC"],
    "Leu" : ["TTA","TTG","CTT","CTC","CTA","CTG"],
    "Ile" : ["ATT","ATC","ATA"],
    "Met" : ["ATG"],
    "Val" : ["GTT","GTC","GTA","GTG"],
    "Pro" : ["CCT","CCC","CCA","CCG"],
    "Thr" : ["ACT","ACC","ACA","ACG"],
    "Ala" : ["GCT","GCC","GCA","GCG"],
    "Tyr" : ["TAT","TAC"],
    "His" : ["CAT","CAC"],
    "Gln" : ["CAA","CAG"],
    "Asn" : ["AAT","AAC"],
    "Lys" : ["AAA","AAG"],
    "Asp" : ["GAT","GAC"],
    "Glu" : ["GAA","GAG"],
    "Cys" : ["TGT","TGC"],
    "Trp" : ["TGG"],
    "Arg" : ["CGT","CGC","CGA","CGG","AGA","AGG"],
    "Ser" : ["TCT","TCC","TCA","TCG","AGT","AGC"],
    "Gly" : ["GGT","GGC","GGA","GGG"],
    "STOP" : ["TAA","TAG","TGA"]}

//letter means
var list = {"A":"A", "B":"CGT ", "C":"C", "D":"AGT","G":"G", "H":"ACT","K":"GT", "M":"AC","N":"ACGT", "R":"AG","S":"CG","T":"T", "V":"ACG", "W":"AT", "Y":"CT"}

//the string what I want to examine
var string = "Phe, Lue, Ser"

//with this function I process string, and get the codons
function GetCodonFromAminoacids(string) {
    var str = string.split(", ")
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        for(key in aminoacids) {
            if(str[i] == key) {
                array.push(aminoacids[key])
            }
        }
    }
}
//array what includes the codons
array = []
GetCodonFromAminoacids(string)


/this code sort the 2D array
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
});

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].sort()
}


/*
array - [Array(6), Array(6), Array(2)]
0: (6) ["CTA", "CTC", "CTG", "CTT", "TTA", "TTG"]
1: (6) ["AGC", "AGT", "TCA", "TCC", "TCG", "TCT"]
2: (2) ["TTC", "TTT"]
*/
```

Comment: you don't need to iterate objects to match keys :`if(aminoacids[str[i]]) array.push(aminoacids[key])`, which kills your inner loop.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. For instance you write *"Second array includes T (second position from TTA)"*, but TTA is in the first array, not the second.

Comment: This is far from an answer but I believe php's usort() function can help you achieve your goal here. Link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php, although just realized this is JS so this npm package looks like it will emulate the php usort function. It's how I'd attempt solving it: http://locutus.io/php/array/usort/

Comment: trincot, thank you for your comment. Sorry if it was misunderstanable. So first array TTA-s second position is T, and I want to examine that T in the second array.